# How to play Microsoft Azure Videos (using azure media player) in lightgallery?

Tags: c#, html, azure, azure-media-services, lightgallery

I am using [slider pro](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro) for showing product image slides and using azure media player's video tag to show videos on sp-slides-container div. The video is playing fine on sp slider but when I click on it and the lightgallery opens it's neither able to play the video nor show the thumbnail due to different HTML structure than slider pro. The following examples are from the console:

```
**lightgallery-all.min.js:4 lightGallery :- data-src is not pvovided on slide item 1. Please make sure the selector property is properly configured. More info - http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/html-markup.html**
```

```html
<div data-vimeo-id class="lg-thumb-item active">
  <img src(unknown)>
</div>
```

And on the preview div:

```html
<div class="lg-img-wrap">
  <img class="lg-object lg-image" src="undefined">
</div>
```

Here the img src is **undefined** because I am using video tag, not img tag in my dynamic html code. It's using data-vimeo-id and img tag but I need to append the  tag there dynamically (which I added in C# controller code with dynamic source and poster url) instead of the default img tag.

How can I define the video tag inside lightgallery dynamically? Is there any better way to do this? Please note that I have no other option except azure media player for showing the videos on the webpage. The images are working fine in the lightgallery because img tags are defined properly but this issue is only happening with video tags.